# Read ReturnUrl (QueryString value) in Login controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've inherited an MVC app, and as a die-hard web forms person, I struggling!
I have a login controller accessible via https://www.myapp.co.uk/Login/Login
There's a model that accompanies it.  So I have...

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember Me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the controller...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Models.LoginModel u)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal cp = MyApp.Identity.Authentication.AuthenticateUser(u.Username, u.Password);
        if (cp != null)
        {
            // process claims here
            // Check ReturnUrl, and if a valid local URL, redirect there, otherwise use 
            // return RedirectToAction("SomeMethod", "SomeController");
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            ModelState.AddModelError("BadUserPass", "Login data is incorrect!");
        }
    }
    return View(u);
}
```

Suppose the URL was this: https://www.myapp.co.uk/Login/Login?ReturnUrl=/SomeController/SomeMethod?someVal=123

Can anyone please advise how, after dealing with the claims, I can check whether the `ReturnUrl` query string part exists, is also a local URL, and if so, redirect there instead of the to current controller?  I tried `Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]` in the controller, but the value is always NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `returnUrl` as a parameter to your controller action.

```
public ActionResult Login(Models.LoginModel u, string returnUrl)
```

The UrlHelper class has a method that checks whether a URL is local, so then it would just be this:

```
if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
 return Redirect(returnUrl);

// Or whatever your default action is
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
```

If you create a new MVC project with the Forms authentication template, this code will be there in the Account controller as an example.

Comment: Can the querystring of the querystring(!) e.g. the 123 value of ` https://www.myapp.co.uk/Login/Login?ReturnUrl=/SomeController/SomeMethod?someVal=123` be parsed?  Redirect(returnUrl) works perfectly, so I'm not sure I even need to bother.  Just after a bit of *best-practice* here...!

Comment: @EvilDr, I just tested it and it should work fine. It looks like it only cares about the first instance of a question mark, anything after is considered part of the value.